freeRADIUS with EAP-TLS client reauthenticate every hour
I've a freeRADIUS configured to handle eap-tls wifi authentication. It works fine other than this hourly re-authentication of every client. I've tried searching online to find any attributes causing this but found none.
I've tried rebuilding the server 2 times with v3.2.5 and 3.2.6 both giving the same result. I've also tried using 2 different APs from unifi and datto with no change at all.
What should I be checking to fix this? freeRADIUS is running on azure vm.
